# Scrapy 1.0 - Configurações de Log

Tags: python, debug, scrapy

Preciso saber como posso fazer para alterar os campos destacados, pois quando eu executo meu programa com Scrapy na versão 1.0 ele imprimi o resultado nestas quantidades destacadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como altera-los, se é através de um script ou das configurações do Scrapy ou até mesmo do Spiders.

Comment: Olá, Caio! Teve algum problema em pôr em prática a resposta do Renan? As stats são como um objeto global para cada job, então basta você obter uma referência a elas e pode alterar de qualquer tipo de componente (spider, pipeline, middleware, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Para mudar os valores das estatísticas geradas durante a execução do spider, você deverá utilizar a interface "Stats Collection".
Manual: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html

**Exemplos:**

1. **Mudar um valor:**

   `stats.set_value('hostname', socket.gethostname())`
2. **Incrementar:**

   `stats.inc_value('pages_crawled')`

O objeto 'stats' é um campo do objeto 'crawler'.

```
crawler.stats.get_value('start_time')
```